# Is it any way to ignore the record that isn't correct and go ahead with the next record while using COPY command to upload data from s3 to redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I have a '.csv' file in the s3 that has a lot of text data. I am trying to upload the data from s3 to redshift table but my data is not consistent , it has a lot of special character. Some records may be denied by the redshift. I want to ignore that record and move ahead with the next record. Is  it possible using COPY command to ignore that record ?

I am expecting exception handling feature while using COPY command to upload data from s3 to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift has several ways to attack this kind of situation.  First there is the MAXERROR option which you can set for how many unreadable rows will be allowed before the COPY will fail.  There is also the IGNOREALLERRORS option to COPY which will read every row it can.

If you want to accept the rows with the odd characters you can use the ACCEPTINVCHARS option to COPY where you can specify a replacement character for every character Redshift cannot parse.  It is typical to use '?' but you can make it any character.